# Netinfo always return true React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to store the fetched API data when reopening a React Native app without internet connection.

I use NetInfo to determine if there is a connection or not, when I console log the ConnectionState.isConnected it is always true even if I disconnect my pc (remove the Ethernet cable and disable wifi).
In case i switch off the mobile data it shows an error (can not connect to debugger).

The functionality works fine in debug APK if I disconnect the internet, but in released APK the first screen appears blank (the data API is not loaded because the condition of checking connection is not satisfied).

This is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
       NetInfo.addEventListener(ConnectionState=> {
       console.log("Connection type", ConnectionState.type);
       console.log("Is connected?", ConnectionState.isConnected);//always true even if i disconnect the internet
     });

   NetInfo.fetch().then(ConnectionState=> {
    if (ConnectionState.isConnected) {
      getArticles(this.state.url)
        .then((data) => {
            // console.log('connection ok!');
            AsyncStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(data));
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
        data: data,
            });
            //DATA SET TO STATE + ASYNCSTORAGE
        })
     }
    else {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('obj').then((value) => {
          // console.log('connection not ok!');
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
            data:JSON.parse(value)
        });
      });
    }
 });
}
```

I added this line in android 
  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`